# How can i debug a failed ci build?

Tags: php, laravel, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

i created some tests with PHPUnit and laravel. The tests are running locally successful, but as a gitlab ci job there is an error.

Here is the ci log:

```
There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Feature\AuthTest::testAuthLoggedInIsAdmin
Expected status code 200 but received 500.
Failed asserting that false is true.

/builds/XXX/webproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php:55
/builds/XX/webproject/tests/Feature/AuthTest.php:53
```

For the better debug and finding a solution i need the error trace from the project or the `error.log` from the webserver.

What is the best practise to debug errors in the ci?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, the solution is very simple... i don't delete the question. Here is the solution:

You have to add an `artifact` to the job. You can set the artifact, that only on failures the artifact is created. If there is an failure on the build, the hole project is dumped to a seperated location. Now you can browse each files on the dump.

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

php-7.0:
  stage: test
  type: test
  services:
    - mysql:latest
  image: tetraweb/php:7.0
  script:
    - bash .gitlab-ci.sh
    - php vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never
  artifacts:
    when: on_failure
    name: "${CI_BUILD_STAGE}_${CI_BUILD_REF_NAME}_FAILED"
    paths:
      - "."
    untracked: false
    expire_in: 1 day

deploy:
  stage: deploy
# etc...
```

[Here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#artifacts) are more informations about artifacts.

You can download the artifacts in the pipelines section in gitlab:

[image: Gitlab Artifacts download]